# How to create add and delete button for listview so next time user open the application added item stays there?

Tags: java, android, listview

I need an answer on how to create an add button to add listview item, and a delete button to delete last added item. Look at my code. I made an add button but that item exists only for a few seconds and every time I close that page (go to other activity in usermode) it is deleted. Please let me know how can I fix this code and how can I write code for delete button. I need to know how to delete last made item. Thanks for your help in advance. I am looking forward to reply.

```
public class dodaj extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    SearchView sv;
    EditText txtinput;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    String[] recepies={};


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dodaj);

        registerClickCallback();


        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        sv=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

        txtinput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtinput);
        Button addbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
        Button buttondel=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondel);
        arrayList= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(recepies));
        addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View v ) {
                String newItem=txtinput.getText().toString();
                arrayList.add(newItem);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });

        buttondel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View v ) {
                int i = arrayList.size()-1;
                arrayList.remove(arrayList.get(i));

            }
        });
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
                return false;
            }
        });



    }

    private void registerClickCallback(){
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {
                TextView textView= (TextView) viewClicked;
                if(position==0){
                    goToMojRecept1();
                }else if(position==1){
                    goToMojRecept2();
                }else if(position==2){
                    goToMojRecept3();
                }else if(position==3){
                    goToMojRecept4();
                }else if(position==4) {
                    goToMojRecept5();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void goToMojRecept5() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MojRecept5.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void goToMojRecept4() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MojRecept4.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void goToMojRecept3() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MojRecept3.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void goToMojRecept2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MojRecept2.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void goToMojRecept1() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MojRecept1.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you need to store those added buttons in a database (sqlite for example) and load them programmatically when the app needs them.

Comment: Because of this: `arrayList= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(recepies));`. You need persistant storage